# Moving eye based on cursor inside an image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm fairly new to javascript/html5. I have a question which I couldn't find in the database of Stack Overflow. I was hoping you guys could help me out!

I have an image
[image: image_noeye] [image: eye]

I would like the eye to move inside the white circle based on cursor position. The cursor position i already have figured out. The only thing I can't figure out is how to implement the images instead of the fillings.

**This is what I got so far:**

```
  function drawEye(eye) {
  bepaalCoordinaten(eye);

  // eye
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(eye.centerX, eye.centerY, eye.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.fillStyle = "#fff";
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();

  // iris
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(eye.centerX + eye.pupilX, eye.centerY + eye.pupilY, eye.radius / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.fillStyle = "#007";
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();

  // pupil
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(eye.centerX + eye.pupilX, eye.centerY + eye.pupilY, eye.radius / 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.fillStyle = "#000";
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();

  context.restore();
}
```

Is there a way replace the iris and eye with the images listed above?

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "move" anything that's been drawn in html5 canvas. Instead, you erase the entire canvas and redraw things in their new positions.

**To redraw your eye at the mouse position:**

1. Listen for mousemove events,

   ```
   canvas.onmousemove=handleMousemove;
   ```
2. On mousemove, clear the canvas

   ```
   context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
   ```
3. Get the mouse position and set your eye object to that position

   ```
   function handleMousemove(e){
        // tell the browser we're handling this event
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        // calc the mouse position
        var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        eye.centerX=parseInt(e.clientX-BB.left);
        eye.centerY=parseInt(e.clientY-BB.top);
   }
   ```
4. Redraw your arm-leg-thing:

   ```
   context.drawImage(thing,0,0);
   ```
5. Redraw your eye:

   ```
   drawEye(eye);
   ```

**Now, apply some basic trigonometry to contain the eye inside the thing:**

```
// test if mouse is outside thing
// if it's outside, contain the eye inside the thing
var dx=eye.centerX-thing.cx;
var dy=eye.centerY-thing.cy;
var dist=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
if(dist>(thing.radius-eye.radius)){
    // mouse is outside thing
    var angle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
    // place the eye on the radius of the thing
    eye.centerX=thing.cx+(thing.radius-eye.radius)*Math.cos(angle);
    eye.centerY=thing.cy+(thing.radius-eye.radius)*Math.sin(angle);
}
```

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var eye={centerX:0,centerY:0,radius:10};
var thing={cx:115,cy:125,radius:75};

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/thing.png";
function start(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
}

function drawEye(eye){
    // demo has simplified eye -- change this to your complex eye
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(eye.centerX, eye.centerY, eye.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle='deepskyblue';
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.stroke();
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // calc mouse position
    eye.centerX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    eye.centerY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
    // test if mouse is outside thing
    // if it's outside, contain the eye inside the thing
    var dx=eye.centerX-thing.cx;
    var dy=eye.centerY-thing.cy;
    var dist=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    if(dist>(thing.radius-eye.radius)){
        // mouse is outside thing
        var angle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
        // place the eye on the radius of the thing
        eye.centerX=thing.cx+(thing.radius-eye.radius)*Math.cos(angle);
        eye.centerY=thing.cy+(thing.radius-eye.radius)*Math.sin(angle);
    }
    // clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    // redraw the thing
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    // redraw the eye
    drawEye(eye);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Move mouse to move the eye.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Still, it looks amazing and that you so much for your response.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work for me..." Please explain. The snippet works fine for me in Windows10 + [Edge|Chrome|Firefox].

Answer (score 1):

There is a method called drawImage:

```
var image_element = document.createElement('img');

image_element.src = "http://placehold.it/50x50.jpg";

image_element.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(image_element, 10, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for my inconclusive response. There's a few things i'm still struggling with. I've put everything in a single HTML file and tried to run it. Could this be because the image is not loading? Sorry If i'm making any obvious mistakes...

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red; }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var eye={centerX:0,centerY:0,radius:10};
var thing={cx:115,cy:125,radius:75};

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/thing.png";
function start(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
}

function drawEye(eye){
    // demo has simplified eye -- change this to your complex eye
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(eye.centerX, eye.centerY, eye.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle='deepskyblue';
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.stroke();
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // calc mouse position
    eye.centerX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    eye.centerY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
    // test if mouse is outside thing
    // if it's outside, contain the eye inside the thing
    var dx=eye.centerX-thing.cx;
    var dy=eye.centerY-thing.cy;
    var dist=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    if(dist>(thing.radius-eye.radius)){
        // mouse is outside thing
        var angle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
        // place the eye on the radius of the thing
        eye.centerX=thing.cx+(thing.radius-eye.radius)*Math.cos(angle);
        eye.centerY=thing.cy+(thing.radius-eye.radius)*Math.sin(angle);
    }
    // clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    // redraw the thing
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    // redraw the eye
    drawEye(eye);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Move mouse to move the eye.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```